# Why run, run configuration etc disabled in Pycharm 2018.1

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

[image]
Im new to python and pycharm and this is my first program when try to run the program i see that run and its configuration is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run it first. Right click on the file name `1.py` in the project folder at the left and select Run. Once you run it you will see the configuration.